# Same MergeSort implementation works fine in C but takes a lot of time in Java

Tags: java, c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've been following an Algorithm and Data Structures course and I decided to implement MergeSort both in C and Java in order to practice what I've learned. The idea is building a vector of a specified size containing random integers and then sort it using the algorithm.

The issue I'm experiencing is that with arrays of size, for example, 100 or more, MergeSort takes a **huge** amount of time to end in Java, while in C ends immediately. With "huge" amount of time I mean that I was able to wait only with inputs of size below 40, otherwise I had to kill the process because after a few minutes it hadn't finished yet. The implementation I've used, though, is the same and it's the one we've been taught at lesson, which takes Θ(nlogn) while being not in-place.

I'm worried there's something happening behind the scenes in Java because I'm allocating a new array everytime the Merge procedure is called, but I can't explain why this is not happening in C too.

Here's the Java code:

```java
public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Building array...");
        int v[] = randomArray(200);
        System.out.println("Sorting...");
        mergeSort(v, 0, v.length-1);
        System.out.println("Array sorted!");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] A, int p, int q){
        if(p < q){
            int r = (p+q)/2;
            mergeSort(A, 0, r);
            mergeSort(A, r+1, q);
            merge(A, p, r, q);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int[] A, int p, int r, int q){
        int[] B = new int[q-p+1];
        int k = 0;
        int i = p;
        int j = r+1;

        while(i <= r && j <= q){
            if(A[i] < A[j]){
                B[k] = A[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                B[k] = A[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i <= r){
            B[k] = A[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while(j <= q){
            B[k] = A[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        
        // Copies the merged array back to A
        for(int a=p; a<=q; a++){
            A[a] = B[a-p];
        }
    }

    public static int[] randomArray(int size){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int v[] = new int[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            v[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

And here's the C one:

```c
void printvector(int *a, int l){
    printf("[ ");
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(a+i));
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
}

void Merge(int *A, int p, int r, int q){
    int B[q-p+1];
    int k = 0;
    int i = p;
    int j = r+1;
    
    while(i <= r && j <= q) {
        if(A[i] < A[j]){
            B[k] = A[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            B[k] = A[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i <= r){
        B[k] = A[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j <= q){
        B[k] = A[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    // Copies the merged array back to A
    for(int a=p; a<=q; a++){
        A[a] = B[a-p];
    }
}

void MergeSort(int *A, int p, int q){
    if (p < q) {
        int r = (p+q)/2;
        MergeSort(A, p, r);
        MergeSort(A, r+1, q);   
        Merge(A, p, r, q);
    }
}


int main(){
    int size = 200;
    int array[size];

    // Building random vector
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        array[i] = abs(rand());
    }

    MergeSort(array,0, size-1); 

    printf("Sorted vector: ");
    printvector(array, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
    public static void mergeSort(int[] A, int p, int q){
        if(p < q){
            int r = (p+q)/2;
            mergeSort(A, 0, r);
            mergeSort(A, r+1, q);
            merge(A, p, r, q);
        }
    }
```

In java version, `mergeSort(A, 0, r);` should be `mergeSort(A, p, r);`

Comment: I can't believe it was that, I've been looking at the code for an hour or so and didn't notice I put 0 instead of p. Thank you so much for your quick response!